# Azure Rest Api Community for developer

Tags: node.js, azure, grouping, rest, azure-sdk

I am a developer and trying to disassociate NSG from subnets using rest API but could not find any good answer please tell me community for Azure Rest API so that I can ask my question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disassociate NSG from subnets, please refer to the following steps

1. Create a service principal and assign contributor role to the sp

```
az login
# it will create a service principal and assign a contributor rolen to the sp
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp"   --sdk-auth
```

[image]

2. code

```
var msRestNodeAuth = require("@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth");
var { NetworkManagementClient } = require("@azure/arm-network");

const clientId = "sp clientId";
const secret = "sp clientSecret";
const domain = "hanxia.onmicrosoft.com";
const subscriptionId = "e5b0fcfa-e****e5fe29f4c68";
async function main() {
  try {
    const creds = await msRestNodeAuth.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(
      clientId,
      secret,
      domain,
    );
    const client = new NetworkManagementClient(creds, subscriptionId);
    const resourceGroupName = "testvnet";
    const virtualNetworkName = "test";
    const subnetName = "default";
    //get the subnet
    const subnetrespose = await client.subnets.get(
      resourceGroupName,
      virtualNetworkName,
      subnetName,
    );
    const subnet = subnetrespose._response.parsedBody;
    console.log(subnet);
    console.log("----------update-----------");
    subnet.networkSecurityGroup = null;
    const res = await client.subnets.createOrUpdate(
      resourceGroupName,
      virtualNetworkName,
      subnetName,
      subnet,
    );
    console.log(res._response.parsedBody);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

main();
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Finally  found my answer by you